# How to configure Google Java Code Formatter in Intellij IDEA 17?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the latest versions of IntelliJ IDEA it seems that it isn't possible to import code style files like [intellij-java-google-style.xml](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml).

I would like use the Google Java Code Style in this IDE but it seems there isn't a trivial solution.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This problem can be solve installing the **google-java-format Plugin**.

1. Open plugins window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>): *plugins*
2. Click on *browse repositories*.
3. Search for *google-java-format*
4. Install the plugin.
5. Restart the IDE.
6. Enable the plugin executing the action (Ctrl+Shift+A): *Reformat with google-java-format* **Update**: in the newer version of the plugin select *Reformat* since the plugin overrides / enhances the functionality of the standard "Reformat" command.

Additional notes from the [google-java-format README](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)

> The plugin will be disabled by default. To enable it in the current project, go to File→Settings...→google-java-format Settings (or IntelliJ IDEA→Preferences...→Other Settings→google-java-format Settings on macOS) and check the Enable google-java-format checkbox. (A notification will be presented when you first open a project offering to do this for you.)
>
> To enable it by default in new projects, use File→Other Settings→Default Settings....

Comment: Just wondering: can the plugin be configured, like: changing the indenting from 2 spaces to 4 spaces?

Comment: @GhostCat Nope. The plugin uses https://github.com/google/google-java-format which is not configurable unless you copy the sources and modify them yourself of course.

Comment: on the Mac, this is CMD+SHIFT+A.

Comment: it worth mentioning that currently import ordering is not supported using the plugin, whilst manually importing the xml file config adding a new scheme style does it.

Comment: for enable it by default for all new projects: File -> New Project Settings -> Preference for new project settings. Then the rest is the same.

Comment: How to use this plugin after enabling it?

Comment: @user As explained in step 6: Ctrl+Shift+A => Reformat with google-java-format

Comment: I found that sticking to IntelliJ's Default Code Style (which is configurable) is better. 
@GhostCat

Comment: We work in a global team, with people using different tools. So a single tool solution won't work for our context.

Comment: When doing Ctrl+Shift+A, there is no "Reformat with google-java-format" option available.

Comment: @HectorRicardo [It says](https://github.com/google/google-java-format#intellij-android-studio-and-other-jetbrains-ides) "When enabled, **it will replace the normal Reformat Code action**, which can be triggered from the Code menu or with the Ctrl-Alt-L (by default) keyboard shortcut." So choose "Reformat code" from Ctrl+Shift+A.

Comment: how do we add specific version of the plugin to intelliJ eg(1.7)?

Answer (score 64):

As mentioned [Here](https://github.com/HPI-Information-Systems/Metanome/wiki/Installing-the-google-styleguide-settings-in-intellij-and-eclipse), Download the intellij-java-google-style.xml file from the [This Link](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml).

Then in Intellij, go Under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style. there in Scheme settings (settings icon on right side) -> import schemes-> intellij idea code style xml.
Select the xml downloaded in first step.
then in Scheme dropdown select the GoogleStyle IDE (newly added style).
Click on apply and close.

Comment: I had the same problem, and was about to add exactly this answer here. Well, upvoting an existing answer is less work though ;-)

Comment: Please note that using the xml code style file will not be 100% match against code formatted with the actual google code formatter. This will become an annoyance if (as you maybe should) you will format the code with google formatter during e.g. a git hook or on CI server.

Comment: For some reason the xml file downloaded from the <This Link> above, couldn't be imported into IntelliJ.
As mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues/325), the xml file at the below link worked:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml

Answer (score 6):

After doing above steps mentioned by Lorenzo, for applying the setting in the current project :-
Intellij>Preferences>google-java-format setting and enable it in intellij; as it wont be enabled by default after doing restart as well.

If you want to have this setting for the projects which will you create after installing this plugin , then Go to File >Other Settings> Default Settings> google-java-format-setting and enable it

Comment: Here's a way to enable the code style for all existing IntelliJ projects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634361/5752730

Answer (score 2):

on a mac this was the easiest for me:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml`

then cmd+, *code style > Java > Scheme (select the gear icon) > import scheme > IntelliJ IDEA code style XML* select the intellij-java-google-style.xml wherever you stored it on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add this xml file to Intellij configuration folder

> /home/USERNAME/.IntelliJIdea17/config/codestyles

Then you can make this code style the default one.

File/Settings/Editor/Code Style  ==>  Scheme = GoogleStyle

Comment: This does not work with new versions (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4)

Comment: this seems more like a hack than a correct solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version(2020.3.2), as mentioned by Gob00st, to enable it by default in new projects, use `File>New Project Settings>Settings for New Projects>Other Settings>google-java-format Settings`

Comment: After enabling, is there any command that I can run to format current file?