# Switch active IntelliJ Code Style for all local projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to standardize my java code style as per [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). I downloaded [intellij-java-google-style.xml](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml), made a few custom tweaks and imported it in IntelliJ in the global IDE section:

> **Preferences...** >> **Editor** >> **Code Style** >> **gear icon** >> **Import Scheme** >> **IntelliJ code style xml**

This applies the Code Style to the current project. However, existing IntelliJ projects keep their existing code style. I can see the new Google Style in the other projects' drop-down menus, but I have to manually reselect it for each project. My problem is I have hundreds of projects.

I would like to automatically select the new Google code style for all existing projects without having to go through the Preferences for each one. But how?

**NOTE:** I don't want to actually auto-format the code in my projects, that would be a git nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ does not provide a way to automatically change code style on existing local repos. So we need to think outside the box.

#### Recursive Search-And-Replace

It turns out IntelliJ stores the active code style in `.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml`:

```xml
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="OldCodeStyle" />
  </state>
</component>
```

We can do a recursive search-and-replace on all the code style config files in a folder and replace the `value` field in each. First, make sure you import the Google Style XML into IntelliJ as described in the question and call it `GoogleStyle`.

Here's the `bash` command. `find` recursively searches for all the paths to `codeStyleConfig.xml`. `sed` replaces the current code style with `GoogleStyle`.

```sh
find ~/projects -name codeStyleConfig.xml -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" -E "s/(.+PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE\" value=\")(.+)(\" \/>)/\1GoogleStyle\3/"
```

> This command has been tested on MacOS 11 and IntelliJ 2020.2. I have not tested on Linux. To understand how the command works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string-with-awk-or-sed) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex). For Windows, you can use Notepad++ to do a regex find-and-replace, install a bash library like `Cygwin` or find `PowerShell` equivalents (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1280022/replace-values-data-in-a-lot-of-xml-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe)).

Answer (score 1):

If you had imported style xml file into `Stored in IDE` from the scheme dropdown menu, then it should be used as default for all your projects.

If you using either Apache Maven or Gradle, you can use [Goggle Java Format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) to format all existing projects.

In my opinion, automatically applied code formatting to existing project would not be a good idea because it will affect the changelog for those projects. It make the code comparison much for meaningless.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! However, I don't want to actually auto-format the code in all projects. What I want to do is to change the Code Style Scheme to the new Google Code Style for all projects so we don't need to go to Preferences > Editor > Code Style > etc. for every project to choose the new Scheme.