# Format Java code using google-java-format in IntelliJ on save

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to find a way to reformat the file on save using the google code formatter maven plugin.

I am able to achieve this on `mvn clean install` but wondering if file format possible on save action in IntelliJ

thanks

Comment: Seem like this was answered [perviously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979700/how-to-configure-google-java-code-formatter-in-intellij-idea-17)

Comment: my question was, how do i make it to format when i press control+s or file autosave

Comment: how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)

Comment: yes this way it can be done. is there anything so that dev doesn't need to add any plugin manually, but plugin can be installed from maven?

Comment: not really as you auto-save is intellij feature, which is not going to trigger the pom. So u need to have plugin installed on the idea to formatted or you need to have plugin to run the maven while saving.

Comment: `is there anything so that dev doesn't need to add any plugin manually` You can configure this plugin to be a [**Required plugin** for the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#required-plugins).